# How to return an arbitrary json object from Asp.net WebApi RC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Before I had this code to return an arbitrary json object with just an id property.
How do I convert this to the new RC version of WebApi now that HttpResponseMessage is not supported and it now uses Newtonsofts JSON.NET?

```
public HttpResponseMessage<JsonValue> Post(MyModel model)
{
            var id = _theService.AddEntity(model);
            dynamic okResponse = new JsonObject();
            okResponse["id"] = id;
            return new CreateResponse<JsonValue>(okResponse);
}
```

And...

```
public class CreateResponse<T> : ResponseBase<T>
    {
        public CreateResponse()
            : base(HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
        }

        public CreateResponse(T resource)
            : base(resource, HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
        }
    }

 public abstract class ResponseBase<T> : HttpResponseMessage<T>
    {
        protected ResponseBase(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
            : base(httpStatusCode)
        {
        }

        protected ResponseBase(T resource, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
            : base(resource, httpStatusCode)
        {


            if (resource is IApiResource)
            {
                var apiResource = resource as IApiResource;
                var resourceLocation = new ResourceLocation();
                apiResource.SetLocation(resourceLocation);
                Headers.Location = resourceLocation.Location;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the RC version of WebApi, but can you show what you try with this new version, and why it is not working?

Comment: HttpResponseMessage<T> is no longer supported and instead of creating a response of type T and passing the content into the constructor, the response is created using an extension method off Request.  Also, NetwonSoft's JSON.Net is used instead of the System.Json types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CreateResponse extention method does not accept dynamic variables.

Please change

```
dynamic okResponse = new JsonObject();
```

to something like

```
var okResponse = new JsonObject();
```

Please see this link also:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359242

Comment: Hi, tried this: var okResponse = new JsonObject(); okResponse["id"] = 101;  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, okResponse); but payload shows {"id":[]} ?

Comment: I was using the System.Json instead of Newtonsoft's version. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hi jaffa, i am also getting the payload like: {"Id":[],"class":[],"address":{"street":[],"zip":[]}}. How you resolved? Can you please show me the code syntax using Newtonsoft's version ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Request.CreateResponse(statuscode, content)` inside your controller

Comment: Ok thanks, but what is the type of 'content'? This gives me a compile error:                 dynamic okResponse = new JsonObject();
                okResponse["id"] = checkResult.NewLeadId;

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, okResponse);

Comment: Also how do you achieve this in ActionFilterAttribute::OnActionExecuting()?  There is no CreateResponse extension on context.Request.? (This is a nightmare)

Comment: Request.CreateResponse is not part of Web API RC. YOu'd need codeplex source or NuGet nightly builds for that.

Comment: Request.CreateResponse IS part of Web API RC as I've just used it. The issue is how to do this in an ActionFilterAttribute.  Still confused about the returning of Json from the CreateResponse() too.

Comment: content is typeof ObjectContent or just your entity instance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but you could just do this:

```
public dynamic Post(MyModel model)
{
            var id = _theService.AddEntity(model);


            return new { id = id };
}
```

EDIT: assuming your client sets the Content-type to application/json